# Lightweight iTunes Home Sharing client

Tags: macos, mac, itunes, music

I have both a MacBook Air & an iMac on the same network. I'm using my iMac as the host with my iTunes library on it & it's being shared with Home Sharing. I'm wondering if there are any lightweight clients that simply connect to a Home Share on the same network to play from it? I'm never going to have a music library on the Air itself, so I don't need to run iTunes if I can avoid it.

Comment: iTunes is pretty lightweight by todays standards anyway – on my Mac it's been open for a few days and is using just under 60MB of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that this is possible. The only things that can connect to an iTunes Home Sharing library are iTunes its self and iPhones (As of iOS 4.3).

Comment: Bummer. I can see myself rsyncing the iTunes library to an external drive and just using that with the Air anyway.